# Making joomla components using two tables

Tags: joomla, components

I know how to make a simple joomla component using one table. I can display all the records from that table as well as add, edit and delete records. I want to know how can i do it using two tables.

Thanks.

Khubruy Mehta

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two models, it can be a good start point: 
http://docs.joomla.org/Using_multiple_models_in_an_MVC_component